# How to populate recycleview from input on another 'screen'

Tags: python, kivy

good day

what im trying to accomplish is to input text on one screen then have it create a button on another screen within a `recycleview` where if I keep adding buttons the `recycleview` keeps getting populated. I would assume that the `button1` function would update the `rvs.rv.data` and that the `recycleview` would use the it update itself.  could you point me in the right direction please?

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager


kv = """
<custombutton@BoxLayout>:
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos
    value: ''
    Button:
        text: root.value
<Root>:
    RVScreen:
        name: 'Rv'
    InputScreen:
        name: 'input_screen'


<InputScreen>:
    name: "input_screen"

    orientation: "vertical"
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"

        TextInput:
            id: textinput

        Button:

            text: "hi"
            on_press: print(app.rvs.rv.data)
            on_press: app.rvs.button1('some_value')

        Button:
            text: 'rvscreen'
            on_press: root.manager.current = 'Rv'

<RVScreen>:
    name: 'Rv'
    rv: rv
    orientation: "vertical"
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"

        Button:
            text: 'refresh'
            on_press: root.rv.refresh_from_data()
            on_press: print(app.rvs.rv.data)

        Button:

            text: "input page"
            on_press: root.manager.current = 'input_screen'


        RecycleView:
            id: rv
            viewclass: 'custombutton'
            RecycleBoxLayout:
                default_size: None, dp(56)
                default_size_hint: 1, None
                size_hint_y: None
                height: self.minimum_height
                orientation: 'vertical'
"""

Builder.load_string(kv)


class Root(ScreenManager):
    pass


class RVScreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(RVScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)


    def button1(self, value):
        self.rv.data.insert(0, {'value': value or 'default value'})


class InputScreen(Screen):
    pass


class TestApp(App):
    rvs = RVScreen()

    def build(self):
        return Root()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are populating the `data` of the `app.rvs`, but that is created by the line:

```
rvs = RVScreen()
```

which creates a new `RVScreen` instance that is entirely unrelated to the `RVScreen` that is displayed in your GUI. In order to update the `RVScreen` in your GUI, you need to get a reference to that `RVScreen`.

I like to that that through a method in the `App`, just because it makes the code simpler. So here is a modified version of your code that does it my way:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager


kv = """
<custombutton@BoxLayout>:
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos
    value: ''
    Button:
        text: root.value
<Root>:
    RVScreen:
        name: 'Rv'
    InputScreen:
        name: 'input_screen'


<InputScreen>:
    name: "input_screen"

    orientation: "vertical"
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"

        TextInput:
            id: textinput

        Button:
            text: "hi"
            on_press: app.add_data(textinput.text)

        Button:
            text: 'rvscreen'
            on_press: root.manager.current = 'Rv'

<RVScreen>:
    name: 'Rv'
    rv: rv
    orientation: "vertical"
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"

        Button:
            text: 'refresh'
            on_press: rv.refresh_from_data()

        Button:
            text: "input page"
            on_press: root.manager.current = 'input_screen'


        RecycleView:
            id: rv
            viewclass: 'custombutton'
            RecycleBoxLayout:
                default_size: None, dp(56)
                default_size_hint: 1, None
                size_hint_y: None
                height: self.minimum_height
                orientation: 'vertical'
"""

Builder.load_string(kv)


class Root(ScreenManager):
    pass


class RVScreen(Screen):
    pass


class InputScreen(Screen):
    pass


class TestApp(App):
    # rvs = RVScreen()  # this code does nothing useful

    def build(self):
        return Root()

    def add_data(self, value):

        # get the `Screen` instance
        rvs = self.root.get_screen('Rv')

        # insert the new value into the data
        rvs.ids.rv.data.insert(0, {'value': value or 'default value'})


if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

I also made a small modification, so that the new `value` comes from the `TextInput`.